# what is selecttype and type when used EXPLAIN in mysql and how i can increase the performance using these results

Tags: mysql

I saw in some places we can see the query details in mysql by using EXPLAIN keyword.
     I am able to see the details.But what `selecttype` and `type` and `possiblekeys` says exactly? and how i can increase performance of my query with the details provided by `EXPALIN`.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)..

Comment: But how i can increase query performance with these details provided by EXPLAIN